# Oracle hierarchical query question (start with ... connect by ... )

Tags: oracle, hierarchy

From [the Oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries003.htm#SQLRF52332):

> To find the children of a parent row, Oracle evaluates the PRIOR
>   expression of the CONNECT BY condition for the parent row and the
>   other expression for each row in the table. Rows for which the
>   condition is true are the children of the parent. The CONNECT BY
>   condition can contain other conditions to further filter the rows
>   selected by the query.

When Oracle select child node for a parent node, it selects from all rows except the current row right? Can a row appear multi times in the result set (I mean a row is both the child node of row A and row B)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would have to be data indicating that the row is both a child of row A and a child of row B.  This can be done, but does not seem like it would be typical.  Think of an employee.  Most employees only have one direct managers.  In a simple design an employee could have two managers, but it would require multiple employee records.  For example:

```
--drop table e;
create table e (id number, name varchar2(100), manager number);
insert into e values (1,'Amos',null);
insert into e values (2,'Bob',1);
insert into e values (3,'Cindy',1);
insert into e values (4,'Dave',2);
insert into e values (4,'Dave',3);
select substr(name,1,7) name, substr(prior name,1,7) Manager
   from e start with id=1 connect by prior id=manager order by name;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear is this is a question about modelling or the hierarchical query itself - but assuming the latter.

> Can a row appear multi times in the result set (I mean a row is both the child node of row A and row B)?

yes, as long as there is no loop in the data, there is no restriction on the way you define what is a 'parent' row and what is a 'child' row:

testbed:

```
create table t as select level as id from dual connect by level<4;
select * from t;

ID                    
----------------------
1
2
3
```

example:

```
select prior id, id, level from t start with id=1 connect by prior id < id;

PRIORID                ID                     LEVEL                  
---------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------
                       1                      1                      
1                      2                      2                      
2                      3                      3                      
1                      3                      2
```

note that in the result, id `3` has two different 'parents'